# In PHP compare 2 csv, add data from 1 csv if there are matches and write to new csv

Tags: php, csv, save, compare

I need to compare two csv files. A new one that i get daily with new products and a second one that contains all products in stock. 
I have tool if therer are the same products in both files by comparing the sku. The first csv with the new products may have the same sku several times. So if there is a match than i need to add the Prod.ID from the second csv to the sku from the first csv in a new column.

This is how the first csv looks like:

```
ID      SKU         Cat         Price
0       12345678    Clothes     10.00
0       12345678    Clothes     10.00
0       87654321    Bath        5.00
```

The second file lookes like this

```
ID     SKU         Cat         Price
321    12345678    Clothes     10.00
532    87654321    Bath        5.00
```

So i need to add the ID from the second csv to every matching SKU in the first csv and save it to a verry new csv to get ist in the end look like this:

```
ID      SKU         Cat         Price
321     12345678    Clothes     10.00
321     12345678    Clothes     10.00
532     87654321    Bath        5.00
```

Right now i have the following code, but i get only a empty updated.csv. I stuck totaly :(

```
$fp = fopen('updated.csv', 'w');

$csvFile1 = "firts-file.csv";
$handle1 = fopen($csvFile1, "r");

$csvFile2 = "second-file.csv";
$handle2 = fopen($csvFile2, "r");

while(($data1 = fgetcsv($handle, 20000, ";")) && ($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 20000, ";" ))) {
    $oldID = $data1[0];
    $newID = $data2[0];       
    if(($data1[1]) == ($data2[1])) {

        fputs($fp, str_replace($oldID, $newID, "\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you have described your 2 input files, **they are not .csv file** So because we do not understand what you are actually asking this question and your other question are not getting answered. **C** stands for Comma **S** stands for seperated **V** stands for variables Your files description contains NOT COMMAS

Comment: If you can try again to properly describe the INPUTS and WHAT YOU WANT DONE and also the format of the OUTPUTS you may actually get someone to attempt an answer

Comment: The input are csv. if i open them in OOo or Excel i get the Coulumns as described above.
what i need is to check both files if there are some same SKU and if so than replace the ID '0' in file 1 with the ID from file to on every match and save the changed data to a new csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.csv** - $result

```
ID      SKU         Cat         Price
0       12345678    Clothes     10.00
0       12345678    Clothes     10.00
0       87654321    Bath        5.00
```

**2.csv** - $source

```
ID     SKU         Cat         Price
321    12345678    Clothes     10.00
532    87654321    Bath        5.00
```

**Code**

```
<?php
    $csvHandleOne = fopen('1.csv', "r");
    $source = $result = array();
    while($data = fgetcsv($csvHandleOne, 2048, ";")) {
        $result[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($csvHandleOne);

    $csvHandleTwo = fopen('2.csv', "r");
    while($data = fgetcsv($csvHandleTwo, 2048, ";")) {
        //We are interested only in SKU and ID link
        $source[$data[1]] = $data[0];
    }
    fclose($csvHandleTwo);

    $csvHandleResult = fopen('result.csv', "w");
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if($key && isset($source[$value[1]])) {
            //SKU => ID link found in source. Set id to $result
            $value[0] = $source[$value[1]];
        }
        fputcsv($csvHandleResult, $value, ';');
    }
    fclose($csvHandleResult);
```

Comment: In order to make an answer useful to the person asking and to future visitors, make sure to include some explanation of what you did, and why it was done.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. 
And sorry for the confusing posts. I tried to edit the first post but after clicking edit i got always the content from my second post. 
once again. Tahnk you. :)